# How to write Nestjs unit tests for @Injectable() mongodb service

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

Can someone please guide me. I'm learning Nestjs and doing a small project, and I'm not able to get the unit test working for a controller and service which has dependency on the database.module. How do I go about mocking the database.module in the product.service.ts? Any help will be highly appreciated.

**database.module.ts**

```
  try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
    return client.db('pokemonq')
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    throw e;
  }
};

@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'DATABASE_CONNECTION',
      useFactory: setupDbConnection
    },
  ],
  exports: ['DATABASE_CONNECTION'],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

**product.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  protected readonly appConfigObj: EnvConfig;

  constructor(
    private readonly appConfigService: AppConfigService,
    @Inject('DATABASE_CONNECTION') => **How to mock this injection?**
    private db: Db,
  ) {
    this.appConfigObj = this.appConfigService.appConfigObject;
  }

async searchBy (){}
async findBy (){}

}
```

**product.service.spec.ts**

```
describe('ProductService', () => {
  let service: ProductService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        ConfigService,
        DatabaseModule,
        AppConfigService,
        ProductService,
        {
          provide: DATABASE_CONNECTION,
          useFactory: () => {}
        }
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get< ProductService >(ProductService);
  });

  afterAll(() => jest.restoreAllMocks());

}
```

product.controller.spec.ts

```
describe('ProductController', () => {
  let app: TestingModule;
  let ProductController: ProductController;
  let ProductService: ProductService;

  const response = {
    send: (body?: any) => {},
    status: (code: number) => response,
    json: (body?: any) => response
  }

  beforeEach(async () => {
    app = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          load: [appConfig],
          isGlobal: true,
          expandVariables: true
        }),
        ProductModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        AppConfigService,
        ProductService,
      ],
      controllers: [ProductController]
    }).compile();

    productController = app.get< ProductController >(ProductController);
    productService = app.get< ProductService >(ProductService);
  });

  afterAll(() => jest.restoreAllMocks());

}
```

Comment: what's wrong with your current solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that is not being tested directly in a unit test should theoretically be mocked. In this case, you have two dependencies, `AppConfigService` adn `DATABASE_CONNECTION`. You're unit test should provide mock objects that *look* like the injected dependencies, but have defined and easy to modify behavior. In this case, something like this may be what you're looking for

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  const modRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [
      ProductService,
      {
        provide: AppConfigService,
        useValue: {
          appConfigObject: mockConfigObject
        }
      },
      {
        provide: 'DATABASE_CONNECTION',
        useValue: {
          <databaseMethod>: jest.fn()
      }
    ]
  }).compile();
  // assuming these are defined in the top level describe
  prodService = modRef.get(ProductionService);
  conn = modRef.get('DATABASE_CONNECTION');
  config = modRef.get(AppConfigService);
});
```

In your controller test, you shouldn't worry about mocking anything other than the `ProdctService`.

If you need more help [there's a large repository of examples here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)

#### Edit 9/04/2020

Mocking chained methods is a major pain point when working with things like Mongo. There's a few ways you can go about it, but the easiest is probably to create a mock object like

```js
const mockModel = {
  find: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  update: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  collation: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  ...etc
}
```

And on the **last** call in the chain, make it return the expected outcome so your service can keep running the rest of the code. This would mean if you have a call like

```js
  const value = model.find().collation().skip().limit().exec()
```

you would need to set the `exec()` method to return the value you expect it to, probably using something like

```js
jest.spyOn(mockModel, 'exec').mockResolvedValueOnce(queryReturn);
```

Comment: I did come across your examples and looking at how its setup and trying your solution. I'll try the above solution and keep you posted. In my example, I'm not using MongooseModule, I'm using the mongodb package.

Comment: The general idea of injection testing isn't dependent on the ORM/Database driver you're working with. I don't use TypeORM or Mongo, but rather a custom driver to postgres using the PG package. The examples are supposed to help show that this is a way to do dependency injection testing, using mocks based on injection tokens

Comment: Thanks :), I'm studying the examples you've put up and it's given me some ideas. I'm going to try it out over the weekend. I read about injection tokens on the Nestjs site but I was unsure how to use it. I'm new to TS and Nestjs :)

Comment: In your above example you've mentioned <databaseMethod>: jest.fn() is the databaseMethod referring to setupDbConnection in my example code snippet inside database.module.ts?

Comment: `<databaseMethod>` is supposed to be a placeholder for whatever methods you use from the injected database dependency. As you didn't provide any of the `ProductService` code, I made the `beforeEach` a little generic.

Comment: I managed to get some tests working but not sure one is complaining about Async  timeout exceeds 5000ms. I found the issue. How do you setup a test mock for model. My service implements this.productModel.find().collation().skip().limit() and I get an error stating this.productModel.find(...).collation is not a function.
....
            collation: jest.fn(),
            skip: jest.fn(),
            limit: jest.fn(),
            findOne: jest.fn(),
            update: jest.fn(),
            exec: jest.fn(),

Answer (score 0):

I am also exploring using native Mongodb with NestJS. Below is my working test for cron job service updating value in db.

src/cron/cron.service.ts

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron, CronExpression } from '@nestjs/schedule';
import { Db } from 'mongodb';
import { Order } from 'src/interfaces/order.interface';

@Injectable()
export class CronService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('DATABASE_CONNECTION')
    private db: Db,
  ) {}

  @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_30_SECONDS)
  async confirmOrderEveryMinute() {
    console.log('Every 30 seconds');

    await this.db
      .collection<Order>('orders')
      .updateMany(
        {
          status: 'confirmed',
          updatedAt: {
            $lte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 30 * 1000),
          },
        },
        { $set: { status: 'delivered' } },
      )
      .then((res) => console.log('Orders delivered...', res.modifiedCount));
  }
}
```

src/cron/cron.service.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { Db } from 'mongodb';
import { CronService } from './cron.service';

describe('CronService', () => {
  let service: CronService;
  let connection: Db;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        CronService,
        {
          provide: 'DATABASE_CONNECTION',
          useFactory: () => ({
            db: Db,
            collection: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
            updateMany: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ modifiedCount: 1 }),
          }),
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<CronService>(CronService);
    connection = module.get('DATABASE_CONNECTION');
  });

  it('should be defined', async () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should confirmOrderEveryMinute', async () => {
    await service.confirmOrderEveryMinute();
    expect(connection.collection('orders').updateMany).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```